# php anomalous behavior setting properties within a for loop

Tags: symfony, for-loop, setter

I have an array generated like this:

```
array:7 [▼
  1 => array:5 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      0 => Receta {#140 ▶}
      1 => Receta {#71 ▶}
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▶]
    2 => array:4 [▶]
    3 => array:2 [▶]
    4 => array:4 [▶]
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▶]
  3 => array:5 [▶]
  4 => array:5 [▶]
  5 => array:5 [▶]
  6 => array:5 [▶]
  7 => array:5 [▶]
]
```

At the end we can find an object (Receta) with a property called 'marca'; then I traverse the array and set the property in a controller like this:

```
public function calculoPersonalizadoAction()
{
    $sesion = $this->get('session');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


    /* GENERATE ARRAY */
    $estructura = new GeneradorDeEstructuraMenu($this->container, $sesion->get('valorId0'));
    $datosEstructurados = $estructura->ordenarEstructurasPorTipos();  

    $menuEstructurado = new EstructuradorDeMenus($sesion->get('recetas'), $datosEstructurados);   
    $recetasEstructuradas = $menuEstructurado->sustituirEnArrayEstructura(); // THIS IS THE ARRAY GENERATED WHAT I WANT TO TRAVERSE

    /* TRAVERSE ARRAY */
    for ($i=1; $i<=count($recetasEstructuradas); $i++){
        for ($n=0; $n<=count($recetasEstructuradas[$i])-1;$n++){
            for ($t=0; $t<=count($recetasEstructuradas[$i][$n])-1;$t++){

            $recetasEstructuradas[$i][$n][$t]->setMarca($i.$n.$t); 
            dump($recetasEstructuradas);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->render('ComponentesBundle:GeneraMenu:calculoPersonalizado.html.twig', array(
        'recetasEstructuradas'=>$recetasEstructuradas,
    ));
}
```

So, I try to get an array like this:

```
array:7 [▼
  1 => array:5 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      0 => Receta {#140 ▼
        -...
        -marca: "100"
      }
      1 => Receta {#71 ▼
        -...
        -marca: "101"
      }
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      0 => Receta {#42 ▼
        -...
        -marca: "110"
      }
      1 => Receta {#71 ▶}
    ]
    2 => array:4 [▶]
    3 => array:2 [▶]
    4 => array:4 [▶]
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▶]
  3 => array:5 [▶]
  4 => array:5 [▶]
  5 => array:5 [▶]
  6 => array:5 [▶]
  7 => array:5 [▶]
]
```

But at the end, I obtain an array like this other:

```
array:7 [▼
  1 => array:5 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      0 => Receta {#140 ▼
        -...
        -marca: "730"
      }
      1 => Receta {#71 ▼
        -...
        -marca: "731"
      }
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      0 => Receta {#42 ▼
        -...
        -marca: "710"
      }
      1 => Receta {#71 ▶}
    ]
    2 => array:4 [▶]
    3 => array:2 [▶]
    4 => array:4 [▶]
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▶]
  3 => array:5 [▶]
  4 => array:5 [▶]
  5 => array:5 [▶]
  6 => array:5 [▶]
  7 => array:5 [▶]
]
```

Note that the object in the position [7][3][0] is the same at the object in the position [1][0][1] and I suppose that when the array is traversed and arrives to [7][3][0], it overwrites the previous same objects.
I'm not sure why this happends inside the loop and what I'm doing wrong when I set the property.
Thanks for responses.

Comment: I deleted my answer, because after looking closer at your array, I realized you start with index 1, not 0. Therefore my answer is wrong and confusing. Sorry, my bad...

Answer (score 1):

Duplicated objects seems to be the same object (look at the hash and number mark, eg #71), so they are passed by reference:

```
 1 => Receta {#71 ▼
    -...
    -marca: "101"
  }
]
1 => array:2 [▼
  0 => Receta {#42 ▼
    -...
    -marca: "110"
  }
  1 => Receta {#71 ▶}
]
```

Ensure you are using `new Receta` within the `EstructuradorDeMenus` class.

Comment: Thanks Kanfor, you're in reason; the problem was that the equal objects inside of the array were by reference; my fix has been to clone all the objects inside of the array and replace its by the originals to get differents and individuals number marks